# Tight big O analysis for program code

Tags: big-o

I have this simple program code. I just wanted to know what the tight big O for this code would be:

```
void main()
{
  int i, j, m, n, a[], b[];

  printf("Enter value of m and n:");
  scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);

  for(i = 1; i <= m; i++)
    a[i] = i*i;
  for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    b[j] = -j;

  for(i = 1; i <= m; i++)
    printf("%d", a[i]);
  for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    printf("%d", b[j]);
}
```

I think Total time complexity T(n) = O(m+n)  i.e. linear time
But can I write it as just O(n) since both are linear anyway?

Comment: Please format your code properly so that it is easier for us to read. And yes it is O(m + n), *but* you can't just write it as O(n) since `m` and `n` are independent variables

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the suggestion.